# scanf() only taking first integer for array

Tags: c++

I am writing a program to sort a user entered array. The following code takes 8 single digit integers to be entered and then put into an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void printArray(int ary[], int n) {
    cout << "The sequence you entered is as follows:" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cout << ary[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    int nums[8];

    cout << "Please enter 8 single digits between 1 and 9" << endl;
    for(int k=0; k<8; k++) {
        scanf("%d", &nums[k]);
    }

    printArray(nums, 8);

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I input digits, only the first integer is pushed into the array with the rest being 0s.
For example, when the input is:
`2,5,7,2,1,4,6,8`. The output is: `2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Comment: You are inputting a `,`. Your `scanf` does not checks for any `,`.

Comment: You should not mix C and C++ IO.

Comment: Is there sometime else I should be using to input then? My program requires the input to be entered on the same line separated by commas.

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of values it successfully read. Checking this can save much debugging.

Comment: Rather than looping 8 `scanf`s you could make one big `scanf` that reads 8 numbers.

Comment: There are a number of ways.  You can see a bunch of example using the google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=read+numbers+separated+by+comma+c%2B%2B+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1SQJL_enUS782US782&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU7KqzwpHhAhUNeKwKHYx9C2kQrQIoBDAAegQIBBAM&biw=1920&bih=937

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input syntax you should use is like that : `2 5 7 2 1 4 6 8`.
or you can change the `scanf("%d", &nums[k]);` to `scanf("%d,", &nums[k]);` and now you can enter `2,5,7,2,1,4,6,8`